# How to handle permalink of sites when migrating a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

**What i want to do:**
Develop a Wordpress-based website with a local Wordpress installation (and xampp).
Migrate this developed website on my webserver.

**What's the problem:**
After putting the website on the webserver each link in the navigation references to "127.0.0.1/wordpress/...".
I'm not even able to login to the Wordpress Backend on the webserver, because the "login.php" (or something) is also referenced on the localhost"

**My Question:**
Do any of you know how I can change this permalinks to the URL of the webserver the website is actually deployed on?

best regards
matt

**edit:**
Another thing that i noticed is, that although I changed the URL in the wp_posts table manually, this database entries are changed by wordpress, so next time, after opening the website, the URLs in the database contains the 127.0.0.1 part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When migrating the database from your local machine to a remote server, you should export your mysql database that is on your local machine to a file. Then perform a search and replace changing "127.0.0.1/wordpress/..." to "www.yourdomain.com/path/to/wordpress" and then import that file to your new mysql database.

Since you have already moved everything over, you can just export the database tables from your remote server to a file, do the search and replace on that, and reimport it. When exporting the database make sure to check "Add Drop Table / Drop View".

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, do everything you need in local, when you're ready to deploy, export your local database from phpMyAdmin, open the file and do "search and replace" your local path with your server path.

Chnage the connection string inside config.php and you're done.

Comment: I already exported the the tables in .sql files and imported them on the webserver.

To adjust the pathes I changed the 127.0.0.1 entries in the "wp_posts" table to the URL of my webserver.

Also i couldn't find a connection string in my config.php

I didn't made use of your "search and replace" suggestion, because the database is already migrated...but maybe this domain change has to be done before that

Comment: i now changed define('DB_HOST', ...) to the url of my webserver, but the links of the navigation still references to 127.0.0.1

Comment: no, you just need to find and replace all your paths in your .sql file and then in your config.php you need to change the values: db name, db user, db pass, etc...